# AutoValue with GsonTypeAdapter in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I am trying to integrate `Kotlin` in an existing android Java project. After making the changes in the build and adding `Kotlin` to the project I can't find a solution to my `AutoValue` classes that have `GsonTypeAdapter` there doesn't seem to be support for this.

```
    @AutoValue
    public abstract class MediaObject implements Parcelable {

    public static TypeAdapter<MediaObject> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
        return new AutoValue_MediaObject.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
    }

    @SerializedName("mimetype")
    public abstract String getMimeType();

    @SerializedName("url")
    public abstract String getUri();
}
```

**`My Gson builder:`**

```
GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new AutoValueGsonTypeAdapterFactory())
```

Any suggestions how to resolve this or what to use instead?

Answer (score 0):

Just dont use it. If it is for Retrofit, you can just use .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) and the kotlin data class.In your case, you need to remove MediaObject java class, and create data class:

```
data class MediaObject(
    @SerializedName("mimetype")
    val mimetypeString:String,

    @SerializedName("url")
    val uri:String)
```